# How to rename file using in PHP Using CURL?

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I need to rename a file in the server FTPS.
I'm using a useful class FTP_Implicit_SSL I have found on the Internet (I need also CURL). I can list directories, upload files, and delete files, however, I cannot rename a file that is in the directory FTP. (The function rename doesn't exist in this library CURL for PHP). I haven't found any function rename here and I am not able to develop a function for renaming.

```
public function rename_aaron($ruta, $nombre_original, $nombre_nuevo)
{
    $sw=0;
    
    if ( ! curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.$nombre_original ))
        throw new Exception ("No se puede establecer el directorio CURL: $this->url");
    
            
    curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url. $nombre_original);
    //curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
    curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            
    
    curl_setopt($this->curl_handle, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array('REN '.$punto_partida_ftp.$ruta.$nombre_original.' '.$punto_partida_ftp.$ruta.$nombre_nuevo)); // RENOMBRAMOS
    if (curl_exec($this->curl_handle))
    {
        $sw=1;// cambiado con exito
        //return 1;
    }
    /*else
    {
        //throw new Exception(sprintf('No se ha podido actualizar el nombre del fichero vía cURL. Error: [%s] - %s', curl_errno( $this->curl_handle ), curl_error( $this->curl_handle )));
        return 0;
    }   */  

    return $sw;
}
```

I would like some of help, please.
Thanks

Comment: moving a file is effectively the same as renaming it. Perhaps there's a "move" function?

Comment: Not sure whether that actually can be done, using this approach. It looks like you are using https://gist.github.com/nalindaDJ/63dea19f07dcfbbf3d33 or similar - and that library makes cURL requests against "FTP URLs" directly, and either uploads a file, or gets the file listing of a folder / content of a file. I don't think you can rename a file using any sort of specific FTP URL, this will need an actual FTP _command_ issued to the FTP server.

Comment: Why not just connect using PHP's [ftp_ssl_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) and then PHP's [ftp_* functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to do what you need?

Comment: I still can't find the solution :(

Comment: Your comment does not help us helping you at all. So did you try what @M.Eriksson suggested? Or is it not feasible?

Comment: Yes, yes, I tried but nothing (sorry for my English)